# Convergence of a series of functions almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm studying for a qualifying exam and having difficulty showing the following:

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2} f(x-\sqrt{n})$ converges absolutely for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I understand that it suffices to show that $\int_\mathbb{R} n^{-1/2}f(x-\sqrt{n})\,dx$ is summable, but I can't seem to show this. Is this even the correct approach?

Comment: Are you sure it's $n^{-1/2}$ ? $\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty |n^{-1/2} f(x-\sqrt{n})|dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \int |f| $ diverges whatever $x$

Comment: This is obviously false (let $f$ be the characteristic function of an interval, for example). What did the problem really ask?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Yes I checked the problem and it is $n^{-1/2}$. It's true that $\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty |n^{-1/2} f(x-\sqrt{n})|= +\infty$, but that doesn't imply that the sum is equal to $+\infty$ for $x$ in a set of positive measure, right?

Comment: @digiboy1 of course not, $\int 1 dx = \infty$ for example

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I checked the problem and it's as it is. If $f$ is the characteristic function of a compact interval as you suggested, wouldn't the sum then becomes just a finite sum for any $x$, and so will converge ? (since $x-\sqrt{n}$ would eventually leave the support of this characteristic function for large enough $n$).

The problem might be false, but is there an explicit counterexample to this?

Comment: @digiboy1 Oh!!! I had totally the wrong picture in mind, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume wlog that $f\ge0$. It's enough to show that $$\sum n^{-1/2}\int_a^bf(x-\sqrt n)\,dx<\infty.$$ By monotone convergence (and translation-invariance of Lebesgue measure) that's the same as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\phi(x)\,dx,$$where $$\phi=\sum n^{-1/2}\chi_{[a-\sqrt n,b-\sqrt n]}.$$So you need only show that $\phi\in L^\infty$. Which it is.

I'll leave the details of that to you; special case this negative that positive something else and you find $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that $$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=A(x)}^{B(x)}n^{-1/2},$$you estimate that sum by an integral and you're done.